# In jQuery, how do I find rows that have a cell with specific text?

Tags: jquery, css-selectors, matching

I have the following HTML table ...

```
<table>
    <tr id="result1">
        <td class="title">Orange</td>
        <td>12</td>
        <td>37</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="result2">
        <td class="title">Apple</td>
        <td>12</td>
        <td>37</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="result3">
        <td class="title">Orange</td>
        <td>12</td>
        <td>37</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="result4">
        <td class="title">Lemon</td>
        <td>12</td>
        <td>37</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Let's say I have the first row ...

```
var $tr = $('#result1');
var title = $tr.find('td.title').text();
```

How in jQuery do I find all the other rows in the table that have a TD cell with class "title" whose text matches what I have in my "title" variable?  Note, in the above example, the only result would be the row with id="result3".

Answer (score 0):

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/j83y0Lxo/)

i just searched through tr except i select. then i match its **title** on my selected **title**

```
let allRow = $("tr");
let selectedRow = $("tr#result1")
let selectedRowValue = selectedRow.children(".title").text();

for (let i = 0, imax = allRow.length; i < imax; i++) {

  if (allRow.not(selectedRow).eq(i).children(".title").text() == selectedRowValue) {
    alert(allRow.not(selectedRow).eq(i).attr("id"))
  }

}
```

feel free to ask :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$("table tr:not(:first-child)")` as selector. This will select the all tr (except the first one since you already query it). Use `filter` to loop thru the `tr` and check the text.

```js
var $tr = $('#result1');
var title = $tr.find('td.title').text();

var rows = $("table tr:not(:first-child)").filter(function() {
  return $(this).find('.title').text() === title;
});

//For testing | add class to the result
rows.addClass("select");
```

```css
.select {
  background-color : pink;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr id="result1">
    <td class="title">Orange</td>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>37</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="result2">
    <td class="title">Apple</td>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>37</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="result3">
    <td class="title">Orange</td>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>37</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="result4">
    <td class="title">Lemon</td>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>37</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

---

If you want to exclude the specific id of the tr instead of the order, you can:

This will exclude the tr with id `#result1`

```
var $tr = $('#result1');
var title = $tr.find('td.title').text();

var rows = $("table tr:not(#result1)").filter(function() {
    return $(this).find('.title').text() === title;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

To query element containing specific text using jQuery, you can use [`:contains() selector`](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/).

In the snippet below, I queried all `td` that contains the `title` then filter out the `td` that's child of `$tr`.

I then loop through the remaining queried `td` and print their `tr`'s id.

```js
var $tr = $('#result1');
var title = $tr.find('td.title').text();

// Get all td.title containing title text
var $tdTitle = $(`td.title:contains(${title})`);

// Filter out the result that is under $tr
var $otherTdTitle = $tdTitle.filter(function(index, td) {
  return $(td).parent().attr('id') !== $tr.attr('id');
});

$otherTdTitle.each(function(index, td) {
  console.log($(td).parent().attr('id'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr id="result1">
        <td class="title">Orange</td>
        <td>12</td>
        <td>37</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="result2">
        <td class="title">Apple</td>
        <td>12</td>
        <td>37</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="result3">
        <td class="title">Orange</td>
        <td>12</td>
        <td>37</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="result4">
        <td class="title">Lemon</td>
        <td>12</td>
        <td>37</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have to combine the suggested `:contains()` selector with `parent()` or `parents()`. Check the code below.

```js
var selector = $("td:contains('Orange')").parent('tr');
$(selector).addClass('highlighted');
```

```css
.highlighted {
background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr id="result1">
        <td class="title">Orange</td>
        <td>12</td>
        <td>37</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="result2">
        <td class="title">Apple</td>
        <td>12</td>
        <td>37</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="result3">
        <td class="title">Orange</td>
        <td>12</td>
        <td>37</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="result4">
        <td class="title">Lemon</td>
        <td>12</td>
        <td>37</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```